# Breaking up a month into individual days on a large table

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to figure out an effective way to break up a month of click data into individual days for a graph, but most of the queries I've put together so far are taking 20-30 seconds because I'm having trouble thinking of a way to do it without subtables \ subqueries.  Best I've come up with so far is:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/09' AND '2018/04/10') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 9th,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/08' AND '2018/04/09') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 8th,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/07' AND '2018/04/08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 7th,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/06' AND '2018/04/07') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 6th,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/05' AND '2018/04/06') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 5th,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/04' AND '2018/04/05') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 6th,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/03' AND '2018/04/04') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 4th,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ( TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/02' AND '2018/04/03') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 3rd
FROM 
( 
    SELECT TIME, BIN_IP FROM CLICKS_IN WHERE USER_GROUP = 4 AND TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/02' AND '2018/04/10' 
)a;
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type    table    partitions   type   possible_keys      key  key_len  ref      rows   filtered   Extra
1      SIMPLE    CLICKS_IN     NULL      ref   USER_GROUP,TIME  USER_GROUP  2   const   1614964    26.65    Using where
```

Or variations thereof, but it's still terribly inefficient given the potential record count (can potentially get 100k+ clicks a day).  Also the actual code uses prepared statements so no need to point that out, I put the values in here for clarity sake.

Edit:  I've found using the following is a -lot- faster but I'm concerned it will run into problems when I have more user groups on the system.

```
SELECT SUM(TIME >= '2018/04/09' AND TIME < '2018/04/10') as 9th,
       SUM(TIME >= '2018/04/08' AND TIME < '2018/04/09') as 8th,
       SUM(TIME >= '2018/04/06' AND TIME < '2018/04/08') as 7th,
       SUM(TIME >= '2018/04/05' AND TIME < '2018/04/07') as 6th,
       SUM(TIME >= '2018/04/04' AND TIME < '2018/04/06') as 5th,
       SUM(TIME >= '2018/04/03' AND TIME < '2018/04/05') as 4th,
       SUM(TIME >= '2018/04/02' AND TIME < '2018/04/04') as 3th       
FROM CLICKS_IN USE INDEX (TIME)
WHERE TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/02' AND '2018/04/10'
AND USER_GROUP = 4
```

Comment: for better performance, i would avoid materializing the derived table.  ... i.e. change `FROM ( SELECT TIME, BIN_IP FROM` to just `FROM`, and remove the closing paren and derived table alias. And check the `EXPLAIN` output to make sure the query is using an appropriate index on the `CLICKS_IN` table. Also note that time values that are exactly at midnight are going to be included in two buckets, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(TIME >= '2018-04-09' AND TIME < '2018-04-10') as 9th,
       SUM(TIME >= '2018-04-08' AND TIME < '2018-04-09') as 8th
FROM CLICKS_IN 
WHERE USER_GROUP = 4 
AND TIME >= '2018-04-02' 
AND TIME < '2018-04-11'
```

And make sure you have indexes on the `time` and `user_group` columns. Then it should run in a few milliseconds.

Comment: I've got indexes on both, and this query is still averaging ~41 seconds.  :

Comment: Please add the output of `explain select ...` to yor question.

Comment: Updated with explain

Comment: @juergend 2 separate indexes would not help with this query would they?

Comment: The `explain` looks ok to me. But you can certainly try it.

Comment: @juergend the explain does not look ok - the `time` predicate is scanned. It should be a composite index there

Comment: It runs extremely quickly when I use only time as the index (which is odd since it would be grabbing all clicks across all user groups), but using only user_group, or both user_group and time makes it run slow as molasses.  Not sure what is causing the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this where each day is returned as a row. Pivoting it from rows to columns could be done more efficiently in the calling PHP code.

```
SELECT
    DAYOFMONTH(TIME) as `day`,
    COUNT(*) as `numclicks`
FROM `CLICKS_IN`
WHERE USER_GROUP = 4 AND TIME BETWEEN '2018/04/02' AND '2018/04/10'
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(TIME)
ORDER BY DAYOFMONTH(TIME)
```

Comment: Functions like `DAYOFMONTH()` can not make use of indexes and are very slow.

Comment: Then don't use the function. The between in the where will limit the rows returned.